# How to do a if condition in a switch statement in c++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int square; char state;
cout<<"Write a numbber"; cin>>square;
square *= square;
cout<<square;
switch(square) {
case 1: state = 'h';
case 3: state = 'm';
case 7: state = 'j';
case (square > 10): state = 'u'; // I try this, but not works
}
return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how a condition is made inside a switch, in c ++.

Comment: switches are not meant to be used this way. However you could put an if statement inside the condition

Comment: In this case, `default:`?

Comment: Use a `default:` case then you can test with an `if` inside that case. That will also allow you to disposition all the other cases that are not `square > 10`. You really need to read your C/C++ language documentation for proper syntax/semantics of switch statements. Guessing that it might be like some other language you may be familiar with is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Are you aware of execution fall-through in switch statements? I'm just wondering if you made it like this for brevity or are about to have a serious bug.

Comment: You should add some break; to avoid multiple state assignations, and your state > 10 looks like default : to me.

Comment: Case statements are blocks of execution so you can use an if statement same as anywhere. You should close each case with a break; to avoid the program executing all the cases afterwards.

Comment: on a tangent, how would an `int` multiplied by itself ever be 3 or 7?

Comment: yes i know that i must use break, and int square cant be 3, is just an example ...

Answer (score 10):

The expression following `case` must be a compile time constant. Hence, you may not use what you are trying.

Change that to `default:` and then use `if`.

```
default:
  if (square > 10)
     state = 'u';
```

Comment: Beat me by mere seconds >:(

Comment: @Thebluefish, I am sure you will get your chance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of items you should use a switch. If not, if else is better.

If a switch contains more than five items, it's implemented using a lookup table or a hash list. This means that all items get the same access time, compared to a list of if:s where the last item takes much more time to reach as it has to evaluate every previous condition first.

If you want to use condition or combine some:

```
switch(square) {
    case 1: state = 'h'; break;
    case 3: state = 'm';break;
    case 7: state = 'j'; break;
    case 8: 
    case 9: state = 'u';
    case 10: state = 'z';break;
    default: state = 'd';
}
```

Case 8, 9, 10 will be combined if the `square` is 8.
If you don't have a break at the end of a `case` region, control passes along to the next `case` label.

Comment: Your code is not, functionally equivalent to OPs. For instance: What happens if someone enters `0`? Not to mention inventing new cases, which wasn't in OPs code, and he is not asking about, just so `default` case would work correctly.

Comment: Concerning the issue, inside a switch, you can put any condition after any case or default label.

Comment: Sure, you can. How is such statement related to my previous comment?